# Proof that $a^2+b^3+c^4=k$ modulo $m$ always has a solution

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Question**

Given integers $m\ge1$ and $0\le k<m$, I want to show that $a^2+b^3+c^4=k \pmod m$ always has a solution.

**Attempt**

It’s easy to show that it is enough to prove this when $m$ is a prime or a power of a prime. I think I can show it for $m=p^k, k \ge 2$, if it is true whenever $m = p$ for some prime $p$. Using the fact that every prime has a primitive root, it is true whenever $m$ is a prime of the form $p = 6n-1$ because $b^3$ takes all values modulo $p$.

For other $p$, $a^2$ has $(p-1)/2 + 1$ different values modulo $p$, $b^3$ has $(p-1)/3 + 1$ different values, and $c^4$ has $\frac{p-1}4 + 1$ different values modulo $p$ if $p-1$ is divisible by $4$, and $\frac{p-1}2 +1$ otherwise. So there are at least $\frac{p^3}{24}$ sums which need to take $p$ different values.

Because of the huge number of combinations, I think the conjecture is true, but I can’t prove it!

PS. This is a necessary condition for the conjecture “every integer is the sum of a square, a cube (of a possibly negative integer), and a fourth power.” which may be quite hard to prove.

Comment: Given your counts of the numbers of squares/cubes/fourth powers, it turns out this follows quickly from the [Cauchy–Davenport theorem](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~hardt040/snt/notes4-27.pdf).

Comment: That’s very interesting. So it didn’t matter at all what numbers I had in my sets, just that the total number of elements of three sets was p+2 or higher. That’s my question answered - but of course almost the same question remains for cases like a^3+b^4+c^5, for example.

Comment: I checked this for p = 1,000,000,009 which is the first prime over a billion where p-1 is divisible by 3 and 4; and every integer from 0 to p-1 equals a^2+b^3+c^4 modulo p for 0 <= a, b, c <= 2,816.